# Dynamic type casting to a generic list of an internal type

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I am using a third party API and I need to access a private field ("_fieldOfB") of an internal field ("_fieldOfA"). The example below illustrates the composition. The field I am looking for is a List of internal types (`ClassC` and `ClassD` are internal and in the same assembly).

```
 public abstract class ClassA
 {
    internal ClassB _fieldOfA;
 }

 public class ClassB
 {
    private readonly List<ClassC<ClassD, int>> _fieldOfB;
 }
```

I have tried with reflection, but I can't seem to get the final type cast right - the dynamic type stays `Object` (note that my class extends `ClassA`)

```
var assemblyHandle = typeof (ClassB).Assembly;
var genericTypeC = assemblyHandle.GetType("ApiNamespace.ClassC`2");
var typeD = assemblyHandle.GetType("ApiNamespace.ClassD");

var genericTypesForC = new Type[] { typeD, typeof(int) };
var typeC = genericTypeC.MakeGenericType(genericTypesForC);
var typeOfList = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeC);

var fieldOfAInfo= typeof(ClassA).GetField("_fieldOfA", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
var fieldOfAValue = fieldOfAInfo.GetValue(this);

var fieldOfBInfo= typeof(ClassB).GetField("_fieldOfB", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
var uncastedFieldOfBValue = fieldOfBInfo.GetValue(fieldOfAValue);

dynamic fieldOfBValue = Convert.ChangeType(uncastedFieldOfBValue, typeOfList);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Forewarning, if you haven't figured this out already... because the items of `ClassC<ClassD, int>` are of an internal type that's not visible to you, that you're going to have to use reflection to work with the list **and** its objects (not just to get the list itself) because you can't work with those types at compile time.

Comment: That being said, have you inspected `uncastedFieldOFBValue` in the debugger to determine that you're actually getting a `List<>` of some sort back from your reflection calls?

Comment: Yes, I've inspected `uncastedFieldOFBValue`using the debugger, and the data is there, but I can't seem to access it as a `List<>`, it stays `Object`

Comment: I've created a workaround by casting to an `IList` and then reflectively obtaining item values from the list one by one. It's not pretty, and most definitely a nasty hack, but it will have to do until the API vendor can release an update to their library.

Answer (score 2):

Something you can do to more easily access the items in the `List<ClassC<ClassD, int>>` (after you've cast the object to `IList`, per the comments) is to use the [`Enumerable.Cast<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method on your list to provide you with an enumeration of [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) objects; this way, instead of using reflection, you can simply have the runtime bind your calls for you.

```
IList nonGenericList = uncastedFieldOfBValue as IList;
IEnumerable<dynamic> dynamicEnumerable = nonGenericList.Cast<dynamic>();

foreach (dynamic obj in dynamicEnumerable)
{
    // work with your objects here
}
```

Of course, this will only allow you to access `public` methods and properties on instances located in the third-party assembly. If you want to play with the internals, you can look at [one](http://igoro.com/archive/use-c-dynamic-typing-to-conveniently-access-internals-of-an-object/) [of](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/05/accessprivatewrapper-c-40-dynamic.html) [these](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/01/18/use-c-4-0-dynamic-to-drastically-simplify-your-private-reflection-code.aspx) blog posts to see how to create a `DynamicObject` wrapper that allows you to bind calls to non-public members using reflection.